# Why a pointer to a char that is passed by value is not finding the null terminator?

Tags: c++, pointers, char, cstring

I've been staring at this for a while now and I'm confused about what is happening in regards to my `for` loop.

To start, I am having the user enter a phrase which is read using `cin.getline()`

```
const int  STRING_MAX  = 1001;
char*      inputString = nullptr;

inputString = new char[STRING_MAX];
cin.getline(inputString, STRING_MAX, '\n');
```

In case anyone is wondering.. I'm not filling up the buffer (which shouldn't matter anyway). I'm only entering about 25 characters.

Next `inputString` is passed by value to the `Palindrome class` member function

```
word(char* source)
```

This is all I'm currently trying to do in the function:

```
bool Palindrome::word(char* source) {
  for (char* iterator = source; iterator != '\0'; iterator++)
    cout << *iterator << endl;
}
```

I'm actually doing more, but at the moment, I reduced the code to what you see above, and for some reason, which I do not understand, the loop runs past the bounds of the `char* array`

Can someone help me to understand what is happening here?

By the way, I am well aware of the string class in C++, however, for this assignment (the instructor wants us to use pointers and the new and delete operators).

Comment: Weird code but one excellently phrased question, +1.

Comment: the test expression in the `for` loop should be written as either `!iterator` or (more completely) as `iterator != NULL`.  (`'\0'` is a NUL byte, not a NULL pointer, though "the usual conversions" will allow it to work regardless of how odd it looks)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`iterator != '\0'`  This tests whether `iterator` is a null pointer.  This will never be the case and it is not what you really want.

Your code is incorrect but just happens to be *valid* code because `'\0'` is a lexical representation of the integer value zero, and is thus it happens to be a null pointer constant.

To test whether `iterator` points to a null terminator, you need to use `*iterator != '\0'` (or just test `*iterator`, since an integer value of zero evaluates to false).

Comment: OMG. Now I feel like a retard. I don't know how I overlooked that. I must be getting tired. Thank you!